# Adding line-height before each line only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some CSS which increases the spacing between lines of text. Obviously, this is done with the CSS `line-height` property. However, as I'd like to apply the same text styles to everything (in an effort to minimize "special case" styles), I want this property to ONLY apply if the text is long enough to wrap onto multiple lines.

I've very nearly got this working the way I'd like, using something like this:

```
p
{
    line-height: 2em;
}

p:first-line
{
    line-height: normal;
}
```

The only outstanding problem is that, because increasing `line-height` adds space both above *and below* each line, and because the first line's `line-height` is `normal`, the spacing between lines 1 and 2 and between any two following lines appears different.

How can I increase `line-height`, such that the extra space appears only **above** each line? I figured `vertical-align: bottom;` might do it, but no luck.

I've made a fiddle to experiment with this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Lp3/).

To help make what I'm looking for a bit more clear, here are some pictures. This is what I get when I simply apply `line-height: 2em;` to `p` tags:

[image: line-height result]

Whereas this is what I want to achieve - notice that the extra space appears **only between** lines, not before or after them:

[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

Achieving this via using `line-height` and then adjusting for the space before the first line and after the last line with negative margins doesn't really do what I wan't; it's a bit of a hack, and if the paragraph has any other styling (like a border, or a background color, or etc.) then it becomes apparent that the lines of text are still too large, and the paragraph itself has simply been set to allow things to overlap that extra space.

Comment: lmk if that worked, or what you decided to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... I don't think it's possible with line-height, ie i don't think you can control this with the line-height css property exclusively. You don't have control over line-height above vs below. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753740/line-height-affecting-spacing-above-first-line-and-after-last-line) if you haven't already.

I think the best thing to do is use a div wrapper. That way you can put any necessary borders on without them being obscured. If you use that in combination with an inner wrapper with negative top and bottom margins, you can achieve the result you desire (See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Lp3/3/) for full example.):

```
<div class="container"><p class="increased">
<span class="line">This is a really long line that will wrap inside this particular div a couple of times to demonstrate "uneven" line spacing.</span>
</p></div>

 div {
background-color: #CCC;
width: 300px;
}
.container {
border:1px solid black;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
.increased {
margin-top:-1.4em;
margin-bottom:-1.4em;
padding:0px;
}
.line {
     line-height: 4em;
   background-color: #FFC;
 }
.increased:first-line {
color:blue;
line-height:normal;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really do what I'm looking for. I've added some pictures and more description to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: i updated it, and it's still a bit of a "hack", but hacked as necessary.

Comment: It seems you're right - this is the best way to do it. It's still not ideal, since it's not exactly something I can put in the e.g. `body` style for all text, but it seems that this is the best way nontheless. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the extra space above only the first line use

```
p {
  margin-top: -1.8em;
}
```